# Is there any errata for the 5e DMG?

Tags: dnd-5e

The treasure table on page 138 is missing the die roll no.10.

Is there any errata for the DMG for that or even in general?

Comment: Not sure if this constitutes an answer, but does that even _count_ as errata? Fixing typographical errors? Also, it's only a few months old, so has enough time even passed?

Comment: Just following the pattern (i.e., just what makes sense, not official), it should be "10–12" where it currently says "11–12".

Comment: That is what I was thinking - since all before are covering 3 results and that one 2.